# Merge raster in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, merge, image

I have a huge problem that I can't solve even after trying everything I can think of. I want to merge 4 rasters as you can see in this image [image]

I have Landsat 8 images, to not have a problem with bands, I have just used Band4 of Landsat 8 and I didn't change their projection EPSG4326 (the same projection for the 4 areas) and for NO Data I have used 0;
[image]
and after I have done the operation of merging them, I have found a problem; only 2 rasters are merged and the two have changed their position like this;
[image]

Comment: Can you explain exactly how you did? Your question only explains the end result not the path you've followed to get it. What are the metadata of each of your 4 files e.g projection, number of bands, nodata value if any? PS: edit your answer for this purpose. Do not hesitate to add more screenshots.

Comment: okey thank you Thomas

Comment: I have edited it

Comment: You have only selected 3 rasters, not 4. Why are you placing the images in separate bands? You want them all in the same band. You just want a bigger band. Don't worry about nodata values if you got all 4 satellite tiles from the same source. If you don't need to, don't merge at all. Build a virtual raster from all 4 images instead. That will save memory.

Comment: I have selected 4 it just doesn't figure il the screen, I don't want them in the same band I want just to create a mosaic of the 4 images ;(

Comment: Based on your screenshot you are running QGIS 2.18. I highly recommend you to update to a newer version if possible and then testing again.

Comment: Okey I will update the newer version thank you very much!